# What are the new elements released via the LEGO Friends sets?

Tags: sets, friends

What new elements did the release of the Friends sets add to the LEGO element parts palette?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As well as the new colours (two new shades each of blue, purple and green), there are actually quite a few new parts in the friends sets. I think this is the complete list, but it's possible I missed one or two. (Let me know of any corrections. It's a big list!)

**Accessories (44)**

- [Friends Accessories Cupcake Holder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543g)
- [Friends Accessories Cutlery Fork](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543i)
- [Friends Accessories Cutlery Knife](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543h)
- [Friends Accessories Dish, Rectangular](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543c)
- [Friends Accessories Dish, Round](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543f)
- [Friends Accessories Frying Pan](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543a)
- [Friends Accessories Hand Mixer](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543d)
- [Friends Accessories Measuring Jug](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543b)
- [Friends Accessories Spatula with Holes](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543e)
- [Friends Accessories Comb with Handle and 3 Hearts](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541d)
- [Friends Accessories Glasses, Heart Shaped with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541k)
- [Friends Accessories Glasses, Oval Shaped with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541l)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Brush with Heart on Reverse](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541a)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Bow with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541j)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Butterfly with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541i)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Flower with Serrated Petals and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541h)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Flower with Smooth Petals and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541g)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Heart with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541e)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Star with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541f)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Tiara with 5 Points and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541m)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Dryer](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541c)
- [Friends Accessories Hand Mirror with Heart on Reverse](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541b)
- [Friends Accessories Basket](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93092)
- [Friends Accessories Lipstick with Light Bluish Gray Handle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb547)
- [Friends Accessories Bag Round with Bright Pink Ruffle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93690pb01)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Clipboard](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393b)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Feeding Bottle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393f)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Ice Pack](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393g)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Nurse Hat](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393h)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Otoscope](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393c)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Pen](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393j)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Spoon](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393e)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Stethoscope](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393a)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Syringe](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393i)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Thermometer](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393d)
- [Friends Accessories Award Ribbon with Number 1](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355e)
- [Friends Accessories Award Ribbon with Number 2](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355f)
- [Friends Accessories Bow](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355d)
- [Friends Accessories Bow with Heart](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355c)
- [Friends Accessories Brush Oval, Large](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355i)
- [Friends Accessories Brush Round, Small](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355h)
- [Friends Accessories Comb, Small with Heart](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355g)
- [Friends Accessories Sponge](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355a)
- [Friends Accessories Spray Bottle with Heart](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92355b)

**Animals (9)**

- [Bird, Sparrow with Red Beak Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98940pb01)
- [Cat Standing, Looking Left with Light Green Eyes, Dark Pink Nose and Mouth and Dark Bluish Gray Stripes Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93089pb01)
- [Dog Small Standing with Blue Eyes, Black Nose and Mouth Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93088pb02)
- [Dog Small Standing with Patch over Eye and Spots Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93088pb01)
- [Dog Small Walking with Blue Eyes and Black Nose and Mouth Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98937pb01)
- [Horse with 2 x 2 Cutout, Blue Eyes and White Blaze Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93083c00pb01)
- [Hedgehog with Reddish Brown Spines Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98944pb01)
- [Rabbit Sitting with Blue Eyes and Pink Nose and Mouth Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98942pb01)

**Flower/Fauna (5)**

- [Friends Accessories Beetle / Ladybug with Stud Holder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081b)
- [Friends Accessories Butterfly with Stud Holder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081a)
- [Friends Accessories Flower Rose with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081c)
- [Friends Accessories Flower with 6 Rounded Petals and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081d)
- [Friends Accessories Flower with 7 Thin Petals and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081e)

**Other Parts (2)**

- [Door 1 x 5 x 3 with 3 Studs and Handle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93096)
- [Panel 1 x 2 x 1 with Rounded Corners and Central Divider](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93095)
- [Minifig, Utensil Handlebars with Angular Handles](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98397)

**Printed Parts (11)**

- [Slope 45 2 x 2 with Red Cash Register and '+15' Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3039pb62)
- [Brick 1 x 1 with Oranges Pattern (Juice Carton)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3005pb017)
- [Brick 1 x 1 with Cow and Flower Pattern (Milk Carton)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3005pb016)
- [Tile 1 x 2 with Cell Phone / Music Player Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3069bpb175)
- [Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Brown Paw Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4150pb84)
- [Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud with Paws and Heart Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3062bpb39)
- [Tile 2 x 4 with 'Andrea' and Music Notes Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=87079pb050)
- [Tile 1 x 4 Lights with CD and Speakers on Light Aqua Background Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2431pb181)
- [Tile, Modified 4 x 6 with Studs on Edges with Blackboard Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6180pb44)
- [Tile 1 x 6 with Ruler Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6636pb043)
- [Tile, Modified 4 x 6 with Studs on Edges with Clothes Design and Swatches Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6180pb45)

**Total: 71, (non-printed parts): 60**

Comment: +1 Wow, You beat me to it by ten minutes AND did a better job of sorting the parts. However the Pie with filling was released [last year](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=col05-9).

Comment: @Ambo100 Ah! I figured there was at least one of those in the list. Should be fixed here in a second. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Holey Moley! I had no idea there would be so many!

Answer (score 4):

I underestimated just how many new parts were produced for the Friends line when I tasked myself with finding out. Excluding the stickers and [Mini-Dolls](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=771) there are a huge number of new piece, the majority of which are either utensils, accessories or pets.

**New parts**

- [Friends Accessories Cupcake Holder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543g)
- [Friends Accessories Cutlery Fork](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543i)
- [Friends Accessories Cutlery Knife](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543h)
- [Friends Accessories Dish, Rectangular](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543c)
- [Friends Accessories Dish, Round](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543f)
- [Friends Accessories Frying Pan](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543a)
- [Friends Accessories Hand Mixer](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543d)
- [Friends Accessories Measuring Jug](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543b)
- [Friends Accessories Spatula with Holes](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb543e)
- [Bright Light Orange Bird, Sparrow with Red Beak Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98940pb01)
- [Cat Standing, Looking Left with Light Green Eyes, Dark Pink Nose and Mouth and Dark Bluish Gray Stripes Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93089pb01) (An awkwardly long name for what is essentially a Freinds scale cat)
- [Friends Accessories Beetle / Ladybug with Stud Holder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081b)
- [Friends Accessories Butterfly with Stud Holder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081a)
- [Friends Accessories Flower Rose with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081c)
- [Friends Accessories Flower with 6 Rounded Petals and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081d)
- [Friends Accessories Flower with 7 Thin Petals and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93081e)
- [Friends Accessories Comb with Handle and 3 Hearts](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541d)
- [Friends Accessories Glasses, Heart Shaped with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541k)
- [Friends Accessories Glasses, Oval Shaped with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541l)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Brush with Heart on Reverse](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541a)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Bow with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541j)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Butterfly with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541i)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Flower with Serrated Petals and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541h)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Flower with Smooth Petals and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541e)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Heart with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541e)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Star with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541f)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Tiara with 5 Points and Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541m)
- [Friends Accessories Hair Dryer](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541c)
- [Friends Accessories Hand Mirror with Heart on Reverse](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb541b)
- [Friends Accessories Basket](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93092)
- [Medium Dark Flesh Dog Small Standing with Blue Eyes, Black Nose and Mouth Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93088pb02)
- [Bright Pink Friends Accessories Lipstick with Light Bluish Gray Handle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb547)
- [Friends Accessories Lipstick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb547)
- [Door 1 x 5 x 3 with 3 Studs and Handle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93096)
- [Dark Orange Horse with 2 x 2 Cutout, Blue Eyes and White Blaze Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93083c00pb01)
- [Dark Orange Dog Small Walking with Blue Eyes and Black Nose and Mouth Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98937pb01)
- [Friends Accessories Medical Clipboard](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98393b)
- Friends Accessories Medical Feeding Bottle
- Friends Accessories Medical Ice Pack
- Friends Accessories Medical Nurse Hat
- Friends Accessories Medical Otoscope
- Friends Accessories Medical Pen
- Friends Accessories Medical Spoon
- Friends Accessories Medical Stethoscope
- Friends Accessories Medical Syringe
- Friends Accessories Medical Thermometer
- [Tan Hedgehog with Reddish Brown Spines Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98944pb01)
- [Bright Light Blue Friends Accessories Bag Round with Dark Pink Ruffle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93690pb02)
- Friends Accessories Award Ribbon with Number 1
- Friends Accessories Award Ribbon with Number 2
- Friends Accessories Bow
- Friends Accessories Bow with Heart
- Friends Accessories Brush Oval, Large
- Friends Accessories Brush Round, Small
- Friends Accessories Comb, Small with Heart
- Friends Accessories Sponge
- Friends Accessories Spray Bottle with Heart
- [White Dog Small Standing with Patch over Eye and Spots Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93088pb01)
- [Rabbit Sitting with Blue Eyes and Pink Nose and Mouth Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98942pb01)

The microphone and custard pie parts have been included only once before in the Collectible Minifigure series. They feature for the first time in a set in the Friends line.

**New printed parts**

- [Brick 1 x 1 with Oranges Pattern (Juice Carton)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98937pb01)
- [Slope 45 2 x 2 with Red Cash Register and '+15' Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98937pb01)
- [Brick 1 x 1 with Cow and Flower Pattern (Milk Carton)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98937pb01)
- Tile 1 x 2 with Cell Phone / Music Player Pattern
- Lime Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Brown Paw Pattern
- Medium Azure Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud with Paws and Heart Pattern
- [White Dish 4 x 4 Inverted (Radar) with 2 Dark Purple Octagonal Circles Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3960pb20)
- [Magenta Tile 2 x 4 with 'Andrea' and Music Notes Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=87079pb050)
- [Red Tile 1 x 4 Lights with CD and Speakers on Light Aqua Background Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2431pb181)
- [Black Tile, Modified 4 x 6 with Studs on Edges with Blackboard Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6180pb44)
- [White Tile 1 x 6 with Ruler Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6636pb043)
- [White Tile, Modified 4 x 6 with Studs on Edges with Clothes Design and Swatches Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6180pb45)

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Good points about the Microphone and Custard Pie elements. The trans-clear Vial in the Laboratory set was similarly only released with a Collectible MiniFig.